# VWD Express 2010 CommandType

Tags: c#, parameters, sqldatareader, vwdexpress

I just converted a website from Foxpro to asp.Net with VB.  I'm now trying to convert to C# and maybe try a few new techniques.  I've not used parameters with datareader before - I found some code that looks similar to what I want to do; however, Intellisense doesn't recognize the command.

```
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

where cmd is of type SqlCommand.  I have a line up top ...

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Is there something else I need to include?

Intellisense is not recognize "CommandType"

Comment: In general press CTRL+. on a highlighted class name and you can let Visual Studio fill in the appropriate `using` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following namespace.

```
using System.Data;
```